Не могу подключиться к ядру СУБД в SQL Server Managment Studio
Не могу подключиться к ядру СУБД в SQL Server Managment Studio (к своему компьютеру). пытаюсь запустить службу SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) но выдает ещё одну ошибку

Если вы укажите, какие ошибки и в какой момент вы получаете, то шансов получить ответ будет больше.
